# Partially specializing parent method in child class

Tags: c++, templates, types, c++20, crtp

I have a template class I would like to specialize for many different types. Something like:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

// To allow static assert for invalid branches
template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool invalid = false;

template <typename T>
struct TypeMeta
{
    using type = T;
    using intermediate_type = T;
    static consteval auto marshal_string() {static_assert(invalid<T>, "Not implemented for type.");}
    static constexpr auto convert(intermediate_type &&value) {return type{value};}
    static constexpr bool needs_conversion = !std::is_same_v<type, intermediate_type>;
};
```

I would like to be able to override parts of this class like so:

```cpp
struct TypeMeta<std::string>
{
    using intermediate_type = const char *;
    static consteval std::string_view marshal_string() {return "s";}
};
```

Then use this further for something like:

```cpp
template <typename T>
T extract_from(void *data)
{
    using meta_t = TypeMeta<T>;
    if constexpr (meta_t::needs_conversion) {
        typename meta_t::intermediate_type tmp;
        tmp = *(static_cast<meta_t::intermediate_type *>(data));
        return meta_t::convert(tmp);
    } else {
        return *(static_cast<meta_t::type *>(data));
    }
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work for `std::string` because I haven't redefined `type`, `needs_conversion`, and `convert` in my specialization.

Now, I can get around this pretty easily by having a base class to inherit from using CRTP. Something like:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct TypeMeta;

template <typename T>
struct TypeMetaBase
{
    using type = T;
    using intermediate_type = T;
    static consteval auto marshal_string() {static_assert(invalid<T>, "Not implemented for type.");}
    static constexpr type convert(intermediate_type &&value) {return type{value};}
    static constexpr bool needs_conversion = !std::is_same_v<typename TypeMeta<T>::type, typename TypeMeta<T>::intermediate_type>;
};

template <typename T>
struct TypeMeta : public TypeMetaBase<T>{};

template <>
struct TypeMeta<std::string> : public TypeMetaBase<std::string>
{
    using intermediate_type = const char *;
    static consteval std::string_view marshal_string() {return "s";}
};
```

Which works just fine. I think it's *slightly* bad that you have to remember to inherit from the base for every type, but that's probably unavoidable.

The *real* problem, however, comes when you want to specialize just the one or two functions you actually need to from the parent. I want to do this:

```cpp
template <>
consteval std::string_view TypeMeta<int>::marshal_string() {return "i"};
```

But this is not allowed:

```cpp
<source>:xx:yy: error: no member function 'marshal_string' declared in 'TypeMeta<int>'
   xx | consteval auto TypeMeta<int>::marshal_string() {return "i";}
```

I can get around this by duplicating the method in my template:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct TypeMeta : public TypeMetaBase<T>
{
        static consteval auto marshal_string() {static_assert(invalid<T>, "Not implemented for type.");}
};
```

Which means that specialized structs like the `std::string` one will fall back to using `TypeMetaBase`'s method if it's not defined, while structs that only have some specialized methods like the `int` one will use `TypeMeta`'s method for ones that aren't specialized.

This means I have to duplicate the code unnecessarily, however. I don't like that. It can easily get out of sync, and it's unnecessary bloat to boot.

Is there any way to avoid having to duplicate methods while allowing minimal extra typing? I suppose I could just demand that any specialization declare its own struct, but there are many different types, most of which only require a single overridden method, and I would prefer to keep it as concise as possible.

One extra idea might be to use a macro for extra struct declarations to avoid the boilerplate, but I would prefer to avoid using macros if possible.

I basically just want to get a nice C++ solution which doesn't involve abusing the preprocessor or copy-pasting code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might split each component in its own type_traits:

```
// All those are customization point
template <typename T>
struct intermediate_type { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
using intermediate_type_t = typename intermediate_type<T>::type;

template <typename T>
consteval std::string_view marshal_string() = delete; // Has to be implemented

template <typename T>
constexpr auto convert(intermediate_type_t<T> value) {return T{value};}

template <typename T>
constexpr bool needs_conversion = !std::is_same_v<T, intermediate_type_t<T>>;

// You might keep the one to group them
template <typename T>
struct TypeMeta
{
    using type = T;
    using intermediate_type = intermediate_type_t<T>;
    static consteval auto marshal_string() { return ::marshal_string<T>();}
    static constexpr auto convert(intermediate_type value) {return ::convert<T>(value);}
    static constexpr bool needs_conversion = ::needs_conversion<T>;
};
```

And then just provide specialization of individual traits:

```
template <>
struct intermediate_type<std::string>
{
    using type = const char *;
};

template <>
consteval std::string_view marshal_string<std::string>() { return "s"; }

template <>
consteval std::string_view marshal_string<int>() { return "i"; }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ms3Wfbd8P)

Comment: Seems about as good as it gets. I'll probably combine the two approaches so you can either specialize a struct or just the function. Thanks!